# DSolve gives no output on system of ODEs

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to get a solution on a classic chase problem

(moving target+rocket with constant speed module)

[image]

Since I'm bad at putting together differential equations, let alone solving them, I tried go get an x[t] and y[t] formulas
Having this input

[image]

And keeping in mind that

```
Vx^2+Vy^2=V^2 (which is constant)
```

The final DSolve is

```
DSolve[{x'[t]/y'[t] == (x[t] - V*t)/(y[t] - y0), (x'[t])^2 + (y'[t])^2 == u^2}, {x[t], y[t]}, t]
```

No output received. What am I doing wrong? Perhaps not enough variables and boundary conditions and it just can't get a solution?

Comment: Interestingly, `NDSolve` works: https://imgur.com/a/CMJPu. But I didn't get `DSolve` to work..

Comment: Mathematica just can't solve these DE's. Even when you boil down your ODE-System to just one DE with `{x'[t],y'[t]}==Normalize[{(V*t+x0)-x[t],y0-y[t]}]*V`. There is an interesting demo on how to solve this numerically though. You can see it here: http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/820972  .

Comment: I need to solve it numerically in c++ with rk4, so I thought i'd get a couple of equations to throw there and solve it. Either I'm an idiot or i need a different approach. Although former is more likely. Thanks anyway)

Comment: Well, when you want solve this with rk4, you can really use the one DE approach suggested by me: `{x'[t],y'[t]}=={(V (t V+x0-x[t]))/Sqrt[Abs[t V+x0-x[t]]^2+Abs[y0-y[t]]^2],(V (y0-y[t]))/Sqrt[Abs[t V+x0-x[t]]^2+Abs[y0-y[t]]^2]}`. You can simply implement this in c++ for a rk4 method.(To be fair, there are 2 DE's but they are much simpler to solve that way.)

Comment: There's Runge-Kutta in MMA: `NDSolve[system, 
 Method -> {"ExplicitRungeKutta", "DifferenceOrder" -> 4, 
   "Coefficients" -> ClassicalRungeKuttaCoefficients}, 
 StartingStepSize -> 1/10]`; see [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveExplicitRungeKutta.html).

Comment: It may be that there is no symbolic solution.  Certainly, `DSolve` will not find one, if `Integrate[x'[t]/(-t V + x[t]), t]` returns unevaluated, and it does.

Comment: @JulienKluge i've done something but i'm not sure i'm having cumulative error when using rk4. euler seems and works fine

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/90191450/main.cpp

Can you take a look and tell me why the speed module is changing with each iteration? Perhaps i'm stealth modifying some of the original variables so it does not work properly? I've double checked, but I may be wrong and I do not have anyone to ask :(
(cout<<... is speed module. comment it if it's too annoying)

Comment: I suggest you ask this in Stackoverflow since its off-topic here.